# Layout background with corners and child layout drawable

Tags: android, android-layout

Anyone got a clue how to handle following issue:

I have a `Layout` with background `drawable` like grey border, then I add `padding` of the border `width` to `Layout.

Child `Layout` has background `drawable` representing a `selector`, when pressed its darker gray (see image) and when not pressed its little bit lighter.

How to get rid of that sharp edge in the picture, I can't add margin to child `Layout`, because the pressed state must fill totally the child `Layout`.

[image: Issue with corner]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only solution here is to add the margin and suck it, or adjust the background drawables to have rounded corners as well.